# Telegram Bot does not recieve messages from channels

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, telegram-bot

I've written Telegram Bot using this [gem](https://github.com/atipugin/telegram-bot-ruby). It works fine when I talk to him directly or in groups.

When I added it to the public or private channel it does not receive any messages at all. Bot has an admin access rights and can send messages, but cannot get it. Moreover, I've tried to switch privacy mode - nothing helps.

Answer (score 2):

As of 03 Feb 2016, bots can't read messages in channels. They can't even get members list. Just posting.